# MPMoviePlayerController release problem

Tags: iphone, performance, memory, memory-leaks, mpmovieplayercontroller

here is code

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application {
  NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
 NSString *moviePath = [bundle pathForResource:@"sample_mpeg4" ofType:@"mp4"];
 NSURL *movieURL = [[NSURL fileURLWithPath:moviePath] retain];


 MPMoviePlayerController *moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:movieURL];
 moviePlayer.movieControlMode =   MPMovieControlModeHidden;

 [moviePlayer play];

 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
 selector:@selector(moviePlaybackDidFinish:) 
 name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification 
 object:nil]; 

 }
- (void) moviePlaybackDidFinish:(NSNotification*)notification
 {

MPMoviePlayerController *theMovie = [notification object];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self                                      name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                                              object:theMovie];
[theMovie stop];
[theMovie release];

[window addSubview:tabBarController.view];
[window makeKeyAndVisible];
}
```

so my problem is my apps memory usage goes additional 3MB , it stays there even after release,does that mean memory does not get released?

Comment: i cant find ans for this que anywhere

Comment: a year later, have you find an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at your code in

```
- (void) moviePlaybackDidFinish:(NSNotification*)notification
MPMoviePlayerController *theMovie = [notification object];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self                                      name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification                                             object:theMovie];
```

Are you sure "theMovie" is your created "moviePlayer"? I believe they are different memory address because you didn't assign a object when you register the notification. Make sure

```
 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
 selector:@selector(moviePlaybackDidFinish:) 
 name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification 
 object:moviePlayer];
```

Then try it again.